# Service Panel and New Underground Conduit

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, conduit

So im remodeling and found out my electrical conduit that carries my lines from the  my garage was rotted out. I had exposed electrical wires, still wrapped in sleeves, but exposed buried in the dirt. The lines came from my detached garage, providers Meter to a main shut off Breaker and then inside the house to a panel. My question is, If when i replace all the metal conduit with Sch 80 pvc pipe, is the white neutral act as a ground? The neutral is hooked up at the main service box to the grounding rod using a #6 solid copper wire. so it goes Grounding Rod > White Nuetral #2 wire > Panel in House ? DO i need to run a #6 from my In house panel to the grounding rod in my detached garage? using the schedule 80 pvc?

Comment: Does the detached garage tap  that power for any purpose?  How is that wired?

Comment: What is the location of the main service box where you say the neutral and ground are tied together?

Comment: The main service box is right next to the meter.

Comment: The detached garage taps into the power for the garage motor and lights inside the detached garage. It is hooked up from the panel inside the house, negative and a positive #12 solid wire line.

Comment: Ok so the main power bypasses the garage, goes to the house where there is a meter, main breaker and service panel, then a #12 cable comes back from the house for garage loads. On the neutral-ground bond, still confused. Is there a grounding rod in the garage?

Comment: Main power , goes to garage, meter, main breaker , then into the house via sch80 then to in-house panel. The #12 from in-house panel to garage.   There is a grounding rod In garage, that is wired to neutral #2.  The